# Django rosetta url strange behaviour

Tags: django, django-rosetta

Django 127.0.0.1:8000/rosetta does not work correctly in DEBUG = True. It will never let you edit translations.

When I change into False it works.

Comment: "does not work correctly" is... not really descriptive of how it don't works. I use rosetta in debug and believe me or not: IT WORKS!

Comment: can you add symptoms, django/rosetta versions...?

Comment: django-rosetta author here. Make sure you use a proper Django cache back-end if you're using the `CacheRosettaStorage` storage.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that when you accessed http://localhost:8000/rosetta/ you where not loged in your app. Go to your login or http://localhost:8000/admin/ and log a valid user for your app, If not, you will get a Page not found (404)